# Unable to persist KUBE-FORWARD custom iptables rule in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, iptables, kube-proxy

I am running kubernetes 1.11.6 and having connection reset issue. For this fix below blog recommend to add iptables rule. When I try to add the rule. it flushed automatically. I assume this is done by kube-proxy

https://medium.com/swlh/fix-a-random-network-connection-reset-issue-in-docker-kubernetes-5c57a11de170

```
iptables -I KUBE-FORWARD 1 -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
```

```
iptables -t filter -L KUBE-FORWARD --line-numbers -n

Chain KUBE-FORWARD (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
2    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes forwarding rules */ mark match 0x4000/0x4000
3    ACCEPT     all  --  10.42.0.0/16         0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes forwarding conntrack pod source rule */ ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
4    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.42.0.0/16         /* kubernetes forwarding conntrack pod destination rule */ ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

After some time, I see it is gone.

```
iptables -t filter -L KUBE-FORWARD --line-numbers -n
```

```
Chain KUBE-FORWARD (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes forwarding rules */ mark match 0x4000/0x4000
2    ACCEPT     all  --  10.42.0.0/16         0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes forwarding conntrack pod source rule */ ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
3    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.42.0.0/16         /* kubernetes forwarding conntrack pod destination rule */ ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

I am trying to persist above rule.

Comment: IP tables are not persistent by default and will be gone after rebooting. Is that the case here? Do you want them to stay even after rebooting?

Comment: All KUBE-* iptables chains are replaced by kube-proxy each time when cluster objects like Pods/Services/Endpoints have changed. You have to put the rule into the FORWARD chain of the filter table. To keep it in place you have to find the way to insert your rule before -j KUBE-FORWARD rule after each node reboot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [iptables-persistent](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-make-iptables-rules-persistent-after-reboot-on-linux).

Install it by executing: `apt-get install iptables-persistent` and any currently erected iptables rulles will be saved to corresponding IPv4 and IPv6:

`/etc/iptables/rules.v4`

`/etc/iptables/rules.v6`

To update persistent iptables with new rules simply use `iptables` command to include new rules into your system. To make changes permanent after reboot run `iptables-save` command:

`iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4`

OR

`ip6tables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v6`

[Here](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Saving_Iptables_Firewall_Rules_Permanently) is an another guide regarding that topic.

Also, the version of Kubernetes that you are running is quite old. Consider upgrading to the more current one.

Please let me know if that helped.